# Ember component being overwritten instead of repeated

Tags: javascript, ember.js, highcharts

I'm new to ember and having some issues. I'm using a modified chart component I found elsewhere on Stack Overflow. My change was to use and ID instead of a class so that hopefully I could have more than one graph.

components/high-chart.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  options: null,
  series: null,
  id: null,

  setId: function() {
    if(this.get('id') === null) {
      this.set('id', 'chart');
    }
  }.on('init'),

  updateSeries: function () {
    this.initializeChart();
  },

  initializeChart: function () {
    var chart = this.get('options');
    chart.series = this.get('series');
    Ember.$('#' + this.get('id')).highcharts(chart);
  },

  didInsertElement: function () {
    this.initializeChart();
    this.addObserver('series', this, this.updateSeries);
    this.addObserver('options', this, this.updateSeries);
  },

  willDestroyElement: function () {
    this.removeObserver('series');
    this.removeObserver('options');
    Ember.$('#' + this.get('id')).highcharts().destroy();
  }
});
```

templates/components/high-chart.hbs

```
<div {{bind-attr id=id}}></div>
```

Here's my template attempting to display the multiple graphs.

templates/transactions/index.hbs

```
<h1>Transactions</h1>
<h2>Maximum</h2>
{{high-chart options=options series=maximumSeries id='maximum-chart'}}

<h2>Minimum</h2>
{{high-chart options=options series=minimumSeries id='minimum-chart'}}

<h2>Average</h2>
{{high-chart options=options series=averageSeries id='average-chart'}}

<h2>Median</h2>
{{high-chart options=options series=medianSeries id='median-chart'}}
```

I've abstracted out the creation of my datasets into a Mixin. I don't think it will be helpful to list however. The datasets are showing the data I want, but the last dataset to be rendered replaces the data on the only chart that renders.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import HighChartTransactionsMixin from '../../mixins/high-chart-transactions';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend(HighChartTransactionsMixin, {
  maximumSeries: function() {
    return this.makeSeriesByTransactions(this, 'maximum');
  }.property('@each', 'sortedTransactionResults.@each.runResultStartTime'),

  minimumSeries: function() {
    return this.makeSeriesByTransactions(this, 'minimum');
  }.property('@each', 'sortedTransactionResults.@each.runResultStartTime'),

  averageSeries: function() {
    return this.makeSeriesByTransactions(this, 'average');
  }.property('@each', 'sortedTransactionResults.@each.runResultStartTime'),

  medianSeries: function() {
    return this.makeSeriesByTransactions(this, 'median');
  }.property('@each', 'sortedTransactionResults.@each.runResultStartTime')
});
```

The page rendered here:

[image: Page rendered]

The source of the page. I notice that the div id=chart is probably the root of my issue, but I don't know how where this id is coming from, or how to change it within my Ember component.

[image: Page elemennts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to have unique element inside unique element?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  setId: function() {
    this.set('elementId', this.get('id'));
  }.on('init'),

  initializeChart: function () {
    var chart = this.get('options');
    chart.series = this.get('series');
    this.$().find('.chart').highcharts(chart);
  }.on('didInsertElement'),
});
```

templates/components/high-chart.hbs

```
<div class="chart></div>
```

Comment: This lead me to a solution! Thanks! I had no idea about elementId.

Answer (score 0):

Mateusz Nowak lead me to the solution, here:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  setId: function() {
    this.set('elementId', this.get('elementId'));
  }.on('init'),

  initializeChart: function () {
    var chart = this.get('options');
    chart.series = this.get('series');
    this.$().find('.chart').highcharts(chart);
  },

  updateSeries: function () {
    this.initializeChart();
  },

  didInsertElement: function () {
    this.initializeChart();
    this.addObserver('series', this, this.updateSeries);
    this.addObserver('options', this, this.updateSeries);
  },

  willDestroyElement: function () {
    this.removeObserver('series');
    this.removeObserver('options');
    this.$().find('.chart').highcharts().destroy();
  }
});
```